# Code that works out whether the word is in ascending order or not

Tags: java

I am new to Java I have created some code that is supposed to work out whether a word that is entered is in ascending order or not. I haven't done anything with booleans so far so I'm not entirely sure how to do this. Currently, it says that the word is in ascending order no matter if that is true or false.

```
class Main
{
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    System.out.print( "#Please enter a word : " );
    String word = BIO.getString();

    while(!word.equals("END")){

        Boolean inorder = true;

        while (inorder)
        {

            for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x = x + 1)
            {
                if (word.charAt (x) >= x)
                {
                    inorder = true; 
                }
                else if (word.charAt (x) < x)
                {
                    inorder = false;
                }

            }

            if (inorder=true)
            {
                System.out.print(word + "letters in ascending order" + "\n");
            }
            else if (inorder=false)
            {    
                System.out.print(word + "letters not in ascending order" + "\n");
            }


            System.out.print("#Please enter a word : ");
            word = BIO.getString();

        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There are various problems here. First, `==` is used for comparison, not `=`. Next, look at *exactly* what you're comparing - `word.charAt(x) >= x` is comparing the character at position `x` with the position itself... not with any other character in the string.

Comment: You need to compare one character with the previous character.  You are currently comparing your character with the position of the character in the word.

Comment: I'm using BlueJ. I understand that the comparison is wrong but I'm not sure how to compare with the previous character?

Comment: Step one: keep track of the previous character as you go through the loop. Step two: compare with that instead of x.

Comment: Of course, there is no need for `==` in the comparison, either, since all that is needed is `if (inorder) { ... } else { ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could need to compare word.charAt(x) with the previous character. Not the position itself.

```
Boolean inOrder = true;

while (inOrder ) {
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    char previous = word.charAt(0);
    for (int x = 0; x < word.length() && inOrder ; x++) {
        inOrder = word.charAt(x) >= previous;
        previous = word.charAt(x);
    }

    if (inOrder ) {
        System.out.print(word + "letters in ascending order" + "\n");
    } else if (!inOrder ) {
        System.out.print(word + "letters not in ascending order" + "\n");
    }

    System.out.print("#Please enter a word : ");
    word = BIO.getString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This has helped. However the problem that I now have is that it doesn't always work, for example if xabcdefgh is entered it will display that it is still in ascending order.

Comment: How would it return true for "xabcdefgh"?

Comment: It displays "xabcdefgh letters in ascending order"? Please help :(

Comment: I am confused as to why "xabcdefgh" is saying it is ascending order. I've tested this twice now.

Comment: Okay, my apologies, when the X is capitalized it produces the error!? Would automatically converting to lowercase get rid of this?

Comment: 'X' is not the same as 'x' and when doing a numeric conversation uppercase letters are higher than lowercase.  To fix this convert all your chars to lowercase

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this considerably - just iterate over the characters in the word, comparing each one to the previous one, and return `false` immediately once you discover it isn't:

```
private static boolean isInOrder (String word) {
    char curr;
    char prev = word.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < word.length(); ++i) {
        curr = word.charAt(i);
        if (curr < prev) {
            return false;
        }
        prev = curr;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at this line:

```
if (word.charAt (x) >= x)
```

What you're doing is comparing your number to x.

For example, say we have the word 'apple', a = 97. What you've done is check if 97 > 0, which is true.

`char` in Java are Unicode characters, therefore when using one as an int, they come out as their Unicode value.

In your code, basically, every word will return that it is larger because of this. Read up on the Primitive types [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)